# Find if a directory exists using Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am searching for a way to find if a directory exist or not using Template Toolkit.

For findind if the directory exists, i am using *Template::Plugin::Directory*

```
[% USE dir = Directory(dirpath) %]
```

In case the directory does not exist and exception will be thrown, so i vatch the exception.

I would wish something like

```
isexists(dirpath)
```

My problem is that *dirpath* request the drive letter, which is not fixed.

Is there a way with Template Toolkit to find the drive letter where my script is running?

Is it possible to find the path of the script which is running?

I am open for other ideas that could some my main problem, finding if a directory exist or not.

**remark**

I am using windows 7 and ProcessTemplate v5.8.0 with Template toolkit v2.22

Comment: The path to the Perl script file being executed is held in `$0`. Does that help?

Comment: I would just check if the directory exists inside your Perl script. If it does, only then invoke your template.

Comment: @Borodin, i do not use perl direct. I only call my template.tt

Comment: Is ProcessTemplate the windows equivalent of `tpage` from the TT package? If so, you could pass the drive letter as a variable `ProcessTemplate --define drive=C: template.tt`

Answer (score 1):

A quick scan of the [source for Template::Plugin::File](https://metacpan.org/source/ABW/Template-Toolkit-2.26/lib/Template/Plugin/File.pm) suggests that if the argument passed in is not an absolute path, it assumes the path is relative to `$config->{root}`, and knowing how TT works, that seems a reasonable thing to do. NB even this is a relative path only.

You haven't said what framework you've got underneath TT, but if it's Catalyst or similar, you might find you can get what you need from

```
[%- c.path_to(c.config.root) -%]
```

... or even (horrors):

```
[%- PERL -%]
    $stash->set(drive => substr($0,0,3)); 
[%- END -%]
[%- SET dirpath = drive _ dirpath -%]
```

... but seriously, don't do that. If you turn on `EVAL_PERL => 1` in your TT config (which you must do for the above `PERL` block to work), just use it to introspect your environment and config so you can find a simple and clean pre-existing variable that holds the info you need.

---

**UPDATE** *based on comment trail*

The original question didn't really get to the heart of the problem, which if I restate as I understand it is this:

*The file I am processing with TT contains references to other files/directories. These references do not include Windows drive letters, which need to be included in order to locate and process these files/directories.*

Now if we were starting with a literal file, then `File::Spec` could be used to convert an relative reference to an absolute one. But all we have is the name of a file, so the drive letter has to be implied from something else: the location of the executing script `$0` *(see above)*, the current working directory `$ENV{PWD}` *(see below)* or a parameter passed to the script, e.g. `--define drive=C:` as Ben Grimm mentioned in another reply.

Try this, which is what I suggested earlier, now presented explicitly: *NB untested*

```
<pre>
[%- PERL -%]
foreach my $e (keys %ENV){
    printf "%s: %s\n", $e, $ENV{$e};
}
[%- END -%]
</pre>
```

That should show you what you have in your environment that might be useful to infer the drive.

Comment: What does _c_ in your example means?

Comment: In Catalyst and similar frameworks, $c is the Web context. You haven't articulated what else is in your stack, so it's hard to know how to advise.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what is TT rendering? Web pages? What is the source of this directory parameter?

Comment: i simply have a file foo.tt2 with TT syntax and text... the aim is generate a xml file. In the xml are fields that dependes of given files exists or not. I do not use perl direct in my scripts, only  ProcessTemplate v5.8 with TT v2.22

Comment: the perl solution return the path to my ProcessTemplate.exe knstead of my tt2 file...

Comment: Well yes, that's what `$0` is. I've updated my answer above with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the current template is available in `template.name`. So I would assume that the drive letter (on windows) could be found by removing from the first / onward:

```
[% drive = template.name.remove('/.*') %]
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, the template files are on the same drive as the directory of interest.

Comment: Right, many assumptions... a better question would yield a better answer.

Comment: @Ben Grimm, it is ensured

Comment: In my testing, `[% template.name %]` contains only the filename without the full path.